# How to use an Arduino in order to control fluids in measured amounts?

Tags: arduino, solenoid-valve, fluid-pump

I am new to the Arduino Platform and the Electronics world. I am currently working on a project which requires accurate fluid controls. By Fluid Control, I mean, pumping a fluid, eg. water, in certain and accurate amounts like ml, from a particular source.

Before, I mention the question, I will specify what I am doing in detail. There will be 3 different sources of the fluid. I have to deliver some amount of fluid from each source to a single container. The amount of fluid taken from each source will vary. The amounts will be in the range from 0 to 1.5 ml. I am planning to use an Arduino to control the entire process.

Now, for my question: Can a mini pump with a motor, deliver the fluid in such minuscule amounts ? If not, then what other options do I have to achieve that ?
Please consider that I have 3 different sources, so refer to a solution which can efficiently control each source independently.

I had thought of using a Solenoid valve instead of the motor. But, I need to decrease space in the project and also do not want an external power source (correct me if I am wrong about this assumption about solenoids).

Any help would be appreciated. Tell me if I am lacking details.
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look for peristaltic pumps.

Comment: Great, Peristaltic Pumps are exactly what I need. But, I checked online and they are quite expensive (in India). Plus, they take up a lot of space. Do you know of any pump which is smaller ?

Comment: For those amounts, Syringe pumps would be better.

Comment: @Delta_Shadow no, they do not come cheap. It's a niche market for laboratories. Maybe cheap ones from aliexpress?